# How do I go from ActivityGroups to Fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, activitygroup

I've been working on a app for the past month which basically consists of a TabControlActivity with a few ActivityGroups within this Tab.

I decided on using ActivityGroups basically because my knowledge as far as Android programming goes is very limited and at the time I had no clue that you're "supposed" to use Fragments for these things(Making sure that the tabwidget persists even if a new activity is started)

Now, Using ActivityGroups has forced me into doing things I really didn't think was needed. [These](http://pastebin.com/W0vM86aR) are the methods I feel like ive been forced to implement in each ActivityGroup to make the application act the way I wanted it to.

I hope I've been able to pain a pretty good picture of my project. What I want to know is how much "effort" and recoding it would take to switch into using fragments instead of ActivityGroups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not narrowed down enough. But from whatever I understood, [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html#Creating) link might help. It says move the code from `activity`'s callback methods to corresponding `Fragment`'s callback methods. Thats a good way to start.

Good luck.